# jquery progress bar not displaying

Tags: html, jquery

I want to have a progress bar for my poll results in my web app and i found this article about jquery progress bar http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_ui_mvc_progressbar.ashx but my problem is the progress bar is not displaying, this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jscript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 37 });
    });
    </script>
```

and this is my div for progress bar

```
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
```

any idea what i am doing wrong?

EDITED: i also used this, and did not work also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 37 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is that a jQuery UI thing? Check your console, you may have an error along the lines of `object has no method progressbar`

Comment: here is an working example: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/ anyway if it doesn´t work you have to paste more code..

Comment: thanks @AlexTape for the link, very helpful, it is displaying now :)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have the `jquery-ui.css` file loaded correctly on the page. Otherwise it won't display anything. This was my problem way back when.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem with the progress bar not showing up when just using the above jQuery code. But the progress bar showed up when I added

```
.ui-progressbar {
  height: 2em;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
  margin: -1px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

to my style.css file. Obviously, the values can be changed to suit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only load jquery once. I had this issue with generated code where two versions of jquery was loaded.